# Exchange 2010 Mailbox Export

Tags: backup, exchange-2010, mailbox

How can I make a backup of an Exchange mailbox to .pst without the end user noticing (aka, not deleting/removing content from the mailbox and not notify the user at all.

Basically we have a sensitive situation where I need to be able to have a very recent backup of email without the user knowing we have a copy.  I know Exmerge doesn't work with 2010, so I'm just looking for some guidance--I have about 2 hours to backup 16GB of mailbox data before some users may end up getting let go.

Answer (score 2):

A user isn't notified when you do a mailbox export, or if you used exmerge.  Either way, for 2010 you need to use the `new-mailboxExportRequest` cmdlet in the Exchange Management Shell and specify a file path to send the PST.  For example:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest jsmith -FilePath "\\server\Psts\jsmith.pst"
```

You also need to give the `Trusted Exchange Subsystem` read/write permissions to the folder you will store the exported PSTs.

As Judaslscariot pointed out, you also need to grant the account performing the export the Import/Export Role.

And you can get further stats on detailed progress with:

```
Get-MailboxExportRequest | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics
```

Which will show you the percentage complete.

Comment: @Top_Hat, please remove your comment, as it provides no further information then my answer.

Comment: I am getting this error:  The term 'new-MailboxExportRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or o
am. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try aga
At line:1 char:25

Comment: Are you running the command from the Exchange Management Shell?

Comment: Nevermind, had to close the shell and reopen after giving my account access to the cmdlets.  Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Your welcome Bob. If you want to make sure the user doesn't delete anything, remove his full access permissions on his own mailbox once he gets laid off, by right-clicking the mailbox in EMC, select "Manage Full Access permissions" and remove the "NT AUTHORITY\Self" account

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Grant yourself the Import/Export role: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633452.aspx

Use:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox "UserToBeLetOff" -FilePath \\server\fileshare\backup_UserMailbox.pst
```

To keep an eye on the progress, use:

```
Get-MoveRequest -Identity "UserToBeLetOff@company.com"
```

2 Hours for 16GB, your kinda in a hurry, but it should be possible, if you choose a fileshare on the Mailbox server as FilePath

Answer (score 1):

You can easily export mailboxes as suggested by @HostBits and @ Mathias R. Jessen

If you are facing "New-MailboxExportRequest command is not recognized" error, There could be several reasons like:

1. Exchange needs an update: For executing New-MailboxExportRequest command, you should have Exchange 2010 SP1 or later version installed.
2. Your account doesn’t have necessary permissions: to assign the role, enter following command in the PowerShell window,

   New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User “DOMAIN\USER”
3. You aren’t running EMS as an Admin: Right-clicking on its icon and selecting ‘Run as Administrator’.

You can check more detailed steps [from here](https://www.stellarservertools.com/blog/new-mailboxexportrequest-not-recognized-exchange-server/).